# Not listing data from mysql in webpage using typeaheadjs (Express server)

Tags: node.js, express, typeahead

I am facing a problem where http://localhost:3000/searchmovie/search?key=%cap works and displays json format of data searched but doesn't display in my web page. 
My Routes is:

```
router.get('/searchmovie/search', function (req, res,next) {
let usedb = `USE moviedatabase`;
databaseconnection.query(usedb, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
});
databaseconnection.query('SELECT moviename FROM movie WHERE moviename LIKE "%' + req.query.key + '%" ', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var data = [];
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    data.push(rows[i].moviename);
    console.log(data);
  }
  res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

My web code is:

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'movies',
            remote:'http://127.0.0.1:3000/searchmovie/search?key=%QUERY' ,
            minLength:2,
            limit: 10
        });
    });
 </script>
 <body>
  <div class="bs-example">
            <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type your Query" data-provide="typeahead">
        </div>
 </body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eEOK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XkyR.png)

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: not getting any errors just data is not being displayed when typed

Comment: I'm guessing your typeahead configuration is the issue her. You should have a look at [the first example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)